# Parse all links on a page, visit them, extract the body copy then continue traversing efficiently

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

So this is what I have:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

root_url = "http://boxerbiography.blogspot.com/2006/11/table-of-contents.html"
file_path = "boxer-noko.html"

site = Nokogiri::HTML(open(root_url))

titles = []
content = []

site.css(".entry a").each do |link|
    titles.push(link)

    content_url = link[:href]
    content_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(content_url))

    content_page.css("#top p").each do |copy|
        content.push(copy)
    end

end
```

But what this does is n^n loops. i.e. if there are 5 links on the main page, it goes to the first one, then in `content` it assigns it the value of all the 5 links (with the current one at the top), then it goes back out and goes to the next one and keeps doing it.

So each piece of content is actually returning the content for every single link, which looks like this:

```
Link 1

Copy associated with Link 1.
Copy associated with Link 2.
Copy associated with Link 3.
.
.
.

Link 2

Copy associated with Link 2.
Copy associated with Link 3.
Copy associated with Link 4.
Copy associated with Link 5.
Copy associated with Link 1.
.
.
.

etc.
```

What I would like it to do is return this:

```
Link 1

Copy associated with Link 1.

Link 2

Copy associated with Link 2.
```

In as efficient a way as possible.

How do I do that?

**Edit1:** I guess an easy way to think about this is that in each array, say `titles`, I would like to store both the link and the content associated with that link. But not quite sure how to do that, given that I have to open two URI connections to parse both pages and keep going back to the root.

So I imagined it like:

```
title[0] = :href => "http://somelink.com", :content => "Copy associated with some link".
```

But can't quite get it there, so I am forced to do it using two arrays which seems suboptimal to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Open the "root" document, extract the links. Then iterate over those links, put the content in a map keyed by the url (content is the value).

Comment: Do you mind showing me a code example? What you say sounds good in theory, but I am having a hard time seeing it in action (with the Nokogiri API and all).

Comment: Example moved to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will create a hash with URL keys, each URL's value is the collection of Nokogiri paragraph elements.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

root_url = "http://boxerbiography.blogspot.com/2006/11/table-of-contents.html"

site = Nokogiri::HTML(open(root_url))

contents = {}
site.css(".entry a").each do |link|
    content_url = link[:href]
    p "Fetching #{content_url}..."
    content_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(content_url))
    contents[link[:href]] = content_page.css("#top p")
end
```

As a sanity check, you can check the contents of one of the keys like this:

```
contents[contents.keys.first]
```

This may or may not be what you actually want, since it'll keep all the inner tags in place (`<br/>`s, `<i>...</i>`s, etc.) but that can be tweaked pretty easily by changing how the contents are gathered. Or it can just be handled through post-processing each URL's contents.

If you want to keep more information about each URL (like the link's text) then you'd probably want to create a tiny wrapper class with url and title attributes.

As it stands, the code doesn't do any checking to make sure each URL is only retrieved once--it might be better to create a `Set` of URLs to force uniqueness, then create the map by iterating over that set's contents (URLs).

Comment: Thanks.....I might have some more questions when I am diving into this later, but this kinda solves my problem. I don't understand it fully...but too tired right now to dive into it :|

So if you can keep checking back, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @marcamillion No problem. Just follow up with a new question; that's the easiest and quicklest :) Or if there's a specific question about this implementation, follow up with a comment, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: How do I see the attributes of the hash? as in, say I want to cycle through the entire hash and just print the `text`, I would do something like: `contents.each do |i|  puts i.text end`. But, when I try that I get an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method ‘text’ for #<Array:0x1017eb768>` So how do I know what attributes I can use to access `content`? 

When I do `puts contents` it outputs the data stored in `contents`. It doesn't tell me `href => http://somelink.com`. 

Also, when I do `puts i[:text]` in that loop, it returns this error: `TypeError: Symbol as array index`.

Comment: @marcamillion Maps are generally iterated over using a 2-arg block, `|key, value|`, or by iterating over its keys, `contents.keys`, and fetching each entry "manually". As I said, each URL's value in the map is an array of Nokogiri elements. Each element will have children when there are embedded tags, like `<i>`. I'll put some further info into a gist and link to it in a few minutes.

Comment: @marcamillion [Gist that writes text-only content to files (in current directory) named after the URL.](https://gist.github.com/1343757) It includes the "poking around" steps I did to figure out what to do as a guide.